# Chrome MBA 2013, causing audio cracking, all flash videos!

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, google-chrome, error, chrome-extensions

I recently purchased a MBA 2013, 13 inch. Used it for a week; was great with Chrome. I suspect after I tried installing some Quicktime plugins to watch an Apple Keynote, my audio started going downhill from there. This resulted in using Safari for the last week, but I cant take it anymore. Need to fix Chrome back.

I've tried
- installing flash again, 
- disabling/enabling different chrome://plugins
[image]
- install, reinstalling chrome using these long patch of commands

```
rm -r /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/
rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/CrashReporter/Google\ Chrome*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome*
rm ~/Library/Preferences/Google\ Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.google.Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.google.Chrome.savedState/
rm ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/Actives/com.google.Chrome
rm ~/Library/Google/Google\ Chrome*
rm -r ~/Library/Speech/Speakable\ Items/Application\ Speakable\ Items/Google\ Chrome/
```

I am willing to do anything really, except re-install a fresh copy of Mountain Lion.
I thank everyone in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem and I have spend several hours on the web trying to find an answer but it sounds like it's the new IOS for mac book problem, as the camera on Skype - not working and if you open Safari with google Chrome the screen will start to crashdown ..